# Prevent iframe scroll capture on youtube iframe embed on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I have a standard youtube embed iframe from a random video:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ixJ5NbvXg_A" frameborder="0"
allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I duplicated this a couple of times to get some scroll overflow.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Mm2eYfj0SgA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Mm2eYfj0SgA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Mm2eYfj0SgA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Mm2eYfj0SgA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Mm2eYfj0SgA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Mm2eYfj0SgA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</body></html>
```

When I serve this using django server on localhost the iframes prevent the page scroll.

When you move your cursor over a video and then use the mousewheel to scroll, it does not work.

The really funny thing is that when I paste the same code and save it to a local file on desktop. Then open it with chrome, the scroll works over youtube videos.

I checked in developer tools, the file served has exactly the same HTML.
There is 100% no CSS or Javascript served, there are no templates, nothing. 
There is only a simple html file in both cases.

Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: You sure that django does not add anything else to the html when it's sent? Also what headers does Django send along with this simple html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My particular issue was a bug in Chrome. It would get solved if I restart the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, the last reply - the https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2229

Comment: it's bad practice to answer using the only link to another source. If you want to provide the answer from GitHub you can copy the piece of code or answer and add like an explanation the link on the source.

Comment: please post full answers

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the css of body like

```
body{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a bug in the browser; here is a simple script that will prevent it from happening. It adds a scroll event to the window which disables pointer events on the iframes whenever the page is scrolling, then re-enables them 100ms after scrolling stops. Since the event is added in capture mode, it fires before the event can be caught by the iframe.

```
<script>

  (function() {

    var iframes, locked = null;
    window.addEventListener("scroll", scroll, true);

    function scroll(e) {

      if (!locked) {
        iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
        lock('none');
      }

      clearTimeout(locked);
      locked = setTimeout(function() {
        locked = null;
        lock('auto');
      }, 100);

    }

    function lock(value) {
      for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
        iframes[i].style.pointerEvents = value;
      }
    }

  })();

</script>
```